# Pinpoint and update a specific IP in all GCP projects firewalls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, ip, firewall

Is there a way (using for instance a series of gcloud api commands on cloud shell), to search through all available GCP projects I have access to, into VPCs, and all networks and firewall rules underneath, for a **specific** IP, and update only *that* IP address without impacting the rest?

Context:
I've whitelisted a static IP over the years in GCP in multiple projects, multiple firewall rules (hundreds) and we're about to change ISP (so the static IP will change). I don't want to hunt down manually, or risk missing some of them (error-prone), I would like to bulk update that IP so it's done all in one-shot.

Or, if not, at the very least, get a list of all entries where that IP might be set.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

UPDATE: 
I wrote this simple script which pinpoints the IPs I want to change at least, hopefully useful to someone!

```
for i in `gcloud projects list| grep -v PROJECT_ID|awk {'print $1'}`
do 
echo $i && gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project $i --format="table(name, network, direction, priority, sourceRanges.list():label=SRC_RANGES, destinationRanges.list():label=DEST_RANGES, allowed[].map().firewall_rule().list():label=ALLOW,denied[].map().firewall_rule().list():label=DENY,sourceTags.list():label=SRC_TAGS,sourceServiceAccounts.list():label=SRC_SVC_ACCT,targetTags.list():label=TARGET_TAGS,targetServiceAccounts.list():label=TARGET_SVC_ACCT)"
done
```

Does not update the IP yet, but at least I can see where they are and I can grep the results for the static IP I am searching for as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach to find all firewall rules with a given source range IP across many projects:

1. Enable Compute Engine API in all relevant projects
2. List projects

```sh
gcloud projects list
```

3. For each project

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules list 
  --project <PROJECT_ID>
  --filter="DISABLED=False AND DIRECTION=INGRESS"
```

4. For each firewall rule

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules describe <NAME> 
  --format="value(sourceRanges)"
```

5. If the output in step 4 matches your IP address, save the name of the rule and then update the source range using

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update <NAME> 
  --source-ranges=<NEW_IP>
```

Some caveats:

- This is a high-level overview of the steps involved, but you probably want to automate this process.
- In a complex environment, this may make a lot of API calls. Make sure you don't exhaust your project quotas in case your other services rely on these API calls to perform their function.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a combination of shell programming and the SDK CLI.

However, it would be much easier to write a Python program using the Google Cloud SDK. It just depends on which environment you are better a developing for (shell or Python programming). The CLI does not have a simple command for this.

Note: This can be done in any language, Python is just an example that is easy to write simple programs in.

To list each firewall rule for each project, you will need to run this command for each project replacing the PROJECT_ID:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project PROJECT_ID
```

Then for each firewall rule output from the previous command display the rules:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules describe NAME --project PROJECT_ID
```

Using your favorite text search program (grep) find the current IP address.

Finalize by updating the rules for the new IP address:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules update NAME <replace with command options>
```

The above commands are the basics using the CLI. You will need to structure this into a program or shell script.

Given that this is a one-off task, I would just use the above commands to list each firewall rule and then grep the output to find the rules that need to be updated. Manually update the rules in the Google Cloud Console from that list.